# Weak star convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

> Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence converging weakly in $C( [0,T] ; L^2(\mathbb{R}^n))$ and also converges in weak star sense in $L^\infty([0,T]; L^2(\mathbb{R}^n))$ to $f$.
>   Can it be concluded that $f_n(t)$ converges weakly to $f(t)$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$? And is the result true if instead, we have $C( [0,T] ; H^{-2}(\mathbb{R}^n))$?

I know in general there are counterexamples to this, but with the additional continuity in time condition, I think it should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Since the evaluation functional $Ef := f(t)$ is linear and continuous from $C([0,T],L^2)$ to $L^2$, it follows $Ef_n\rightharpoonup Ef$, which is the weak convergence $f_n(t)\rightharpoonup f(t)$ in $L^2$.

Comment: How do we use the second info about $L^\infty$?

Comment: Never. This weak-star convergence is weaker than the weak convergence in $C([0,T],L^2)$.

Comment: I think it is used to guess the weak limit of $f_n$ , since we are not given any candidate.